How to deny directory listing and allow direct access to files in Sharepoint Online
We are trying to migrate local file server to Sharepoint Online, and we need ability to deny directory listing. The application works on way that share direct link to files depending on user permissions. We want to implement the same, but I can't find. Thank you!
There are no suitable permission

Does your application currently provide file sharing functionality through the IIS server? Do you need to migrate this functionality to SharePoint Online? I don't quite understand your question, please correct me if I understand it wrong.

My application generate table in SQL Server that contain direct links to files shared by IIS in local server. And then we have RLS filtering on SQL Server table only relevant rows by user profile.
What are preventing from users to get irrelevant documents it's deny of directory listing. I can't use direct permission because I have more than 500000 files, and users have various permissions, and I can't group them
